# apache pig rank operator not working with multiple reducer

Tags: hadoop, hive, apache-pig

I am trying to use pig's `rank` operator to assign integer number for a given string. Although it works when I set the `parallel` clause to 1, it doesn't with a higher value (like 200). I need to use multiple reducer to speed up the processing since by default, pig is only using one reducer, which takes a long time.

My query is as follows :

rank = rank tupl1 by col1 ASC parallel 200;

Comment: Please add details on what does not work. If there is an error message, could you please show it ? Also, did you try with less than 200 reducers (like 2, for instance) ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually according to the pig documentation (https://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.11.1/perf.html#parallel) :

> You can include the PARALLEL clause with any operator that starts a
>   reduce phase: COGROUP, CROSS, DISTINCT, GROUP, JOIN (inner), JOIN
>   (outer), and ORDER BY.

That's why you have an error I think, it's not possible to set the PARALLEL parameter for rank.